# Error : No unix socket support on windows connecting mongodb

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I'm using robomongo tool to access mongodb. When I connect into my db then

[image]

Show error details

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: @shA.t the same error

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by removing the full url (for example: `mongodb://myuser:mypassword@mongodb-test.mydomain.com/my_database`) in the connection tab and only putting in the mongodb server url: `mongodb-test.mydomain.com`.

Next, in the Authentication tab, I checked the Perform authentication checkbox, specified the Database, user name, password.

I also added the database in the Advanded tab just in case and I can now connect without error.

Comment: Using `mongodb-test.mydomain.com` portion for the address and following authentication part worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Try inserting only e.g: `ds12345.mlab.com` at address bar instead of full `[http:// mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@...]` and create user to authenticate in `mlab.com` and then try connect to it. Something like this:

[image]

And then:

[image]

Comment: Why would connecting to a different remote mongo db help them?

Comment: That's just example remote address. you can use your own remote address.

Comment: this is good also, i was able to connect to mlab remote address using this same with OP error

Comment: With whom using tools like Robo 3T, please see the accepted answer, also remember to split your DbUser, DbPassword, DbName to Authentication tab, split you port to port textbox, keep the rest for the URL, it's should work

Answer (score 7):

Whilst this answer is only partly related to the problem, I want to describe the solution in here.

I had this problem when trying to connect via Robo3T to a cluster of MongoDBs hosted on Atlas. They offer a connection string with the protocol in front (e.g. `mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@database-mongodb.net/admin`). This was a combination of two problems:

1. Robo3T does not like the protocol `mongodb+srv://` in the URI. You should use only the second part (after the `@`). Like: `database-mongodb.net`.
2. Robo3T does not like shards. At least I could not get to connect with it via that connection string. Fro what I understand, you need that protocol to connect to a shard. Since you can't use that kind of URI, you will need to connect directly to the primary shard. To do that, you need to build a new connection string with the URI of the primary shard. Like this: `database-shard-00-00-vemhh.mongodb.net` and provide the port to Robo3T. Also, you need to connect via SSL, if you're using MongoDB Atlas (a self-signed certificate configured directly in Robo3T worked for me).

Answer (score 4):

Remove only `[http://]` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Get the newer version of the Robo3T client...it can import it automatically from +srv link

[image: Robo 3T 1.3.1]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, but I can solve it by installing Robo 3T 1.3 and import connection details from MongoDB SRV connection string. See this:

[Steps to connect remote DB from Robo 3T 1.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX7nc.jpg)

Remember to replace the user in the connection string and the pass at Authentication Tab

The connection string in the picture is dummy by the way