# Meteor app hosted on Cloud9 - How to connect to the MongoDB with Robomongo?

Tags: meteor, cloud9, robo3t

I have an app built with Meteor in Cloud9. And i want to connect to the MongoDB database of the the app using Robomongo, but i cant get it working..

I run the app by typing "meteor --port $IP:$PORT", and it runs ok.

When i type "meteor mongo" in the Cloud9 terminal it shows:
[image: Typing meteor mongo in terminal]

So i figure the MongoDB is running on port 8081?

Then on Robomongo, i enter the actual app URL and port, but it fails.

[image: Robomongo connection screen]

This is the error i get:

[image: Robomongo Error]

And this is when i click "Show error details":

[image]

Comment: Looks like your robomongo is able to reach your server but not connect to your db. Does your mongodb have any username / pwd authentication? Also, what's the error details when you click on "Show error details"

Comment: @blueren The error details says: "Cannot connect to the MongoDB at [my-app-url]:8081. Error: No unix socket support on windows". I don't think i have a username or password for the MongoDB because in Cloud9, i only need to type "meteor mongo" and i'm in the mongo terminal.

Comment: Okay. (1) Try removing the ```https://``` from the address and give it another go? Basically, your address should be only the url without the ```https://``` and the trailing '/' (2) In the advanced tab, give in the default database name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the fully qualified URL from the address. In your case, only have `meteor-appname-username.c9users.io` instead of `https://meteor-appname-username.c9users.io/`
2. In the advanced tab, give in the default database name (in your case: `meteor`)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279643/error-no-unix-socket-support-on-windows-connecting-mongodb)

Comment: Doesn't work, now it can't connect at all. It says: Failed to connect to meteor-appname-username.c9users.io:8081. (with the real URL of course).

Comment: Strange that it worked for others. Take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279643/error-no-unix-socket-support-on-windows-connecting-mongodb

Comment: I see.. it's not working in my case. Well i guess my problem has something to do with Cloud9.. and the ports that it lets MongoDB listen to or something like that..