# MongoDB: No unix socket support on windows

Tags: linux, windows, mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I use Robo 3T as a UI tool for MongoDB on a Windows 8 machine. Now I've deployed the DB to production on a Ubuntu 14 server in Amazon EC2 cloud. When I try to connect from the Windows machine to the Ubuntu one via Robo 3T, I receive the following error:

> Cannot connect to the MongoDB at [http://12.345.678.90]:27017.
>
> Error: No unix socket support on windows

Is that a problem I need to fix on my computer by installing something? or it's an issue of Mongo 3T?

If it's an issue on my Windows, what do I have to install in order to make it work?

If it's a Mongo 3T issue, do you know another UI that does support connecting from Windows to Ubuntu?

Perhaps an EC2 solution?

Or maybe some settings I need to change in Robo 3T?

I've tried changing "http" to "mongodb" to no avail. I've also tried removing the protocol prefix as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279643/error-no-unix-socket-support-on-windows-connecting-mongodb) but I ended up with the error:

> Cannot connect to the MongoDB at 12.345.678.90:27017.
>
> Error: Network is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a bindIP setting in your mongo configuration file? Probably that can cause the error.
Either remove the bindIp configuration or allow your IP to access mongo server.
(restart your service after changes the configuration).

Comment: What's the location and name of mongo configuration file?

Comment: /etc/mongod.conf
If you don't have a configuration file, you need to create one and start mongo with that configuration. Check this out https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/

Comment: I think /etc/mongod.conf is the location on Linux, but as I've mentioned I use Windows. What's the location on Windows?

Comment: you need to create a config file first. That can be done in any directory. Then start mongo with that configuration file.