# Connecting to new MongoDB on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, robo3t

I installed the mongodb community edition on a Ec2 instance on my AWS. The installation went well and I was able to run the mongo command.

I then followed this tutorial: https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/

In order to create a user and a database. I then opened the port 27017 on my aws security group for this instance.

I keep trying to connect to my new database with the user and database and password I created however it won't let me. I am using Robo 3T to make the connection.

I used this code to create my user:

```
use build_db

db.createUser({
    user: 'admin',
    pwd: 'secretpassword',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'build_db'}]
});
```

When I type the show users command in terminal mongo i just get this error
" Error: not authorized on test to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0, $db: "test" } :
"

Anyone know how I can get this to connect and work via Robo 3T. Thanks in Advance!

Update: Now it seems as though I can't even connect to mongo shell.

I get this error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-04-27T22:13:41.983+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-04-27T22:13:41.983+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The readWrite permission is rather limited, and is most likely the reason you cannot execute  the users command via the Terminal (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWrite).

If this user is meant to have admin privileges, you might instead wish to set the role as dbOwner (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#dbOwner).

Comment: i re created the entire instance and setup and created a admin user with access to any database and when i try typing mongo i just get this error:

2018-04-27T23:30:37.810+0000 I STORAGE  [main] In File::open(), ::open for '/home/ubuntu/.mongorc.js' failed with Permission denied
The ".mongorc.js" file located in your home folder could not be executed

Comment: correct. I can connect using my ssh to my terminal with putty. However when I try entering the user creds I made for admin to connect via Robo 3T. it just wont connect. I even made sure port 27017 is open on aws.

Comment: the only time i get it to say connect on robo3T is if i actually write mongodb:// in front of the IP but then it gives me a "No unix socket support on windows" and authorization failed on the user

Comment: this provides some alternatives to try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279643/error-no-unix-socket-support-on-windows-connecting-mongodb

Comment: yes I had already seen that before I posted my question. It did not work for me unfortunately...

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved this issue for anyone else who faces it moving forward! The best way to connect is to set the database url to local host. Then add the SSH key and creds to the ssh tunnel section. I left the user area unchecked. Was able to connect via Robo 3T successfully! Hope this helps anyone facing the issue in the future.